# Suggest some efficient algorithm in linear time

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

You have an array `A` of length `N` consisting of positive integers. Let's consider `N` vertical segments (parallel to y axis) on the plane, the `i`-th segment connects the points `(i, 0)` and `(i, Ai)`.

You have Q queries of following two types:

`+ i X : Ai += X`

`? i L R`: Let's consider `R - L + 1` rays which are parallel to x axis. The j-th ray eminates at point `(i - 0.5, L+ j - 1.5)` and extends to the right infinitely long parallel to x axis. You have to print the number of the segments that will be shot by some ray. If a ray shoots a segment then it stops at that point and does't extend further.

Note that all the queries of the second type are independent of each other.
Code I tried produces right result but not much efficient:

```
int main()
{
    int T;
    int k;
    cin>>T;
    long int N,Q;
    for(k=0;k<T;k++)
    {
        cin>>N>>Q;
        vector<long int> v;
        v.push_back(-1);
        long int i=0,p;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            cin>>p;
            v.push_back(p);
        }
        for(long int j=0;j<Q;j++)
        {
            char c1;
            cin>>c1;
            if(c1=='+')
            {
                long int i;
                int X;
                cin>>i>>X;
                v[i] = v[i] + X;
            }
            else
            {
                long int L,R,i;
                cin>>i>>L>>R;
                long int count=0,max=-100000;
                for(long int l=i;l<=N;l++)
                {
                    if(v[l]>=L && v[l]>max)
                    {
                        max=v[l];
                        count++;
                        if(max>=R)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                cout<<count<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

T is here no of test cases.N is total no of elements in the array. Q is the no of queries on that array.  So what I need is a better algorithm to do the same job that I did.

Comment: StackOverflow is not your personal coding service. What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: It would be better if you give the link to the question itself, if it happens to be from one of the competitive coding platforms.